# Summing consecutive third numbers in python

Tags: python

How would I solve this?

The program should contain the definition for the function `sumTri(cutOff)`. The function adds Tri numbers into the sum.

Tri numbers are every third number: `1, 4, 7, 10,` .... The function adds consecutive Tri numbers `1, 4, 7,` ... into the sum so long as the Tri number is less than the cutOff. The function returns the sum of these numbers.

Comment: Homework, I'm assuming?  (It's okay if it is; just means we should give hints rather than a solution.)  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

It's simple:

```
def sumTri(cutOff):
  return sum(range(1,cutOff,3))
```

Or, when you need it lowlevel:

```
def sumTri(cutOff):
  sum = 0
  tri = 1
  while tri < cutOff:
    sum += tri
    tri += 3
  return sum
```

I'll try to explain both soultions a little bit.

In the first case you use two "highlevel" functions of Python, that make all work for you: `sum` and `range`. The `range(a,b,c)` function generates a list of numbers from `a` to `b` with the step `c` between. E.g.:

```
In [1]: range(1,10,3)
Out[1]: [1, 4, 7]

In [2]: range(1,22,3)
Out[2]: [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]
```

You must note here that `range` generates numbers until the number in the list is less than `b`, not less-or-equal. Exactly what you need for your task.

And `sum` obviously calculates and returns the sum of the numbers in the list that it has as its argument:

```
In [3]: sum([1])
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: sum([1,2])
Out[4]: 3

In [5]: sum([1,2,3])
Out[5]: 6
```

Now you need just to combine these two functions:

```
return sum(range(1,cutOff,3))
```

The second solution is more "lowlevel" and "algorithmic". You use no special python functions here and do everything yourself.

You use two variable to calculate the sum:

- `sum` -- the variable where you store your sum
- `tri` -- the variable with the current value of number that you add step by step

When you write something like:

```
a = a + 5
```

that means: "Now I want `a` to be equal to what `a` was before plus 5" or "increase `a` by 5". You can write it shorter:

```
a += 5
```

These two forms are equivalent.

But you need not simple add something. You need to do it for many times until something is happened. In python you do it using `while`:

```
while someting-is-true:
  do-something
```

Every time `while` checks the `something-is-true` condition, and when it's True, it makes commands that are under `while` (indented) i.e. `do-something`.

Now you know all necessary to write the solution:

```
def sumTri(cutOff):
  sum = 0                      # we start the sum from 0
  tri = 1                      # and the first number to add is 1
  while tri < cutOff:          # next number to add < cutOff?
    sum += tri                 # than add it to sum
    tri += 3                   # and increase the number by 3
  return sum                   # now you have the result, return it
```

That was the function that makes the job. Now you can use the function.
How you do this?

```
def sumTri(cutOff):
  ...

# anywhere in you program:
# presuming a is the cutOff
print sumTri(a)
```

when you want to run the function and use its result you just write `function_name(args)`.

Comment: [How to ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @andrew, julio: Thank you for suggestion, added explanation

Comment: For cutoff of 1000000, my answer is ~40000 times faster

Comment: @gnibbler: you are like young euler :)

to Reyer: I suggest you to consider the brilliant solution from gnibller also. The function makes no "summing", the function just `know` the answer. It takes constant time to give calculate the answer (the same for 10 and 1000000).

Comment: +1 to @gnibbler: the point of this assignment is to recall basic arithmetic progressions stuff and use that.

Answer (score 4):

This sequence is related to [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_numbers)

Here is one that is O(1)

```py
def sumTri(cutoff):
    n = (cutoff+1)//3
    return (3*n-1)*n//2
```